# How do I order this with html and css?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

After having connected an api, I need to sort the data that it gives me.
I have configured the columns but it only responds to one and orders each card one below the other.

How do I get them to be side by side within the columns I want?

I also want to modify that where it says buy and next the price is one below the other.

I leave the html code and the api connection.

index:

```
<div class="container body-content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                
                <div id="price"></div>
                
                <hr>

                <h1><b>*</b> (1) Aclaración importante sobre 'Dolar Bolsa':
                    La compra y venta de "Dolar Bolsa" o "Dolar MEP" 
                    corresponde a operaciones con títulos valores, no 
                    implicando en ningún momento el acceso al mercado de 
                    cambios en el marco de las regulaciones establecidas por 
                    el Banco Central de la República Argentina.</h1>
                <br />

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

api:

```
function fetchData() {
fetch("https://www.dolarsi.com/api/api.php?type=valoresprincipales")

  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    const filteredOutput = data.filter(item => {
      switch (item.casa.nombre) {
        case "Dolar Blue":
        case "Dolar Oficial":
        case "Dolar Bolsa":
        case "Dolar Contado con Liqui":
        case "Dolar turista":
        case "Bitcoin":
          return item;
          break;
        default:
          return null;
      }
    })
    let html = "";
    filteredOutput.forEach(item => {
      
      html += "<div class=\"col-12 col-lg-6\">";
      html += "<div class=\"card bg-c-blue order-card\">";
      html += "<div class=\"card-block\">";
      html += "<div class=\"user\">";
      html += "<h6 class= \"nombre\">" + item.casa.nombre + "</h6>";
      html += "<div class=\"row\">";
      html +=  "<div class=\"col-6 text-center\">";
      html += "<p class= \"compra\"> COMPRA " +item.casa.compra + "</p>";
      html += "</div>";
      html +=  "<div class=\"col-6 text-center\">";
      html += "<p class= \"venta\">  <small>VENTA</small><span</span> $ " + item.casa.venta + "</p>";
      html += "</div>";
      html += "</div>";
      html += "</div>";
      html += "</div>";
      html += "</div>";
      html += "</div>";

    })

    document
      .querySelector('#price')
      .insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", html);
  });
}

fetchData();
```

Comment: Perhaps you can post the desired HTML structure and layout, so that we will have a better understanding.

Comment: Filter should return true or false not null or the item. You can perform a `filteredOutput.sort` to sort it. You can clean up your html by doing it in a single template literal (using backticks).

Comment: Can you please draw some layout boxes of current layout and desired layout !!

Comment: I need help with the order of the cards where the information is displayed. It is now one below the other and not responding to columns.
I would like them to look like this website: www.dolarhoy.com

Comment: and I would also like to modify the number of decimal places that the api gives me in the numbers. for example: I would like it to be 140.40 and not 140.402